# impossible to access grub from usb install stick

Tags: grub-efi, xps

I am not sure this has been asked.. but i did not find

I have ubuntu on a usb flash drive

i can boot a dell xps 9560 with it but i need to edit the boot to disable the nouveau driver by setting `nouveau.modeset=0`

however whatever I try i am not able to prevent ubuntu from booting as I cannot stop the counter to edit the grub configuration the black grub menu displays for 0.001 second and I tried everything: pressing esc key, pressing button arrows, f6, any key space bar impossible to stop the counter to then press e, edit the boot parameter and then boot.

when i boot without setting the kernel parameter mentioned above i cannot install ubuntu on the laptop... it appears to install fine but when it time to reboot it doesnt boot and the only way to reboot is to long press power button but then i cannot boot anything.

is there a way to edit the ubuntu iso or from the live ubuntu to add the kernel parameters

if I edit /etc/default/grub from within the live environment it does not help because system is readonly

I am at loss any way i can edit the grub menu?

the ubuntu i try to install in 18.4.2 lts the laptop is xps 9560, in uefi mode with secure boot enabled.

Comment: Have you tried holding the `shift` key during boot? Editing `/etc/default/grub` won't help because it is not used by grub directly. It is parsed when generating `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` (e.g. when running `update-grub`). Do you have access to any other system except the live system?

Comment: i have windows that came preinstalled.. with the laptop.. I am trying to  install ubuntu on an exteral usb-c hard disk. buy without disabling the nouveau drivers it will not help.

Comment: After installing Ubuntu to the USB-C drive, can you select that drive to boot from in the BIOS/UEFI?

Comment: no because I am forced to hard boot it.. and all i get after booting is a grub prompt.. this means the install does not finish properly.. if i exit the grub prompt it boot windows

Comment: by "grub prompt" do you mean "grub boot menu" or "grub command line"?

Comment: the grub boot menu.. where you edit the kernel line to pass `nouveau.modeset=0`.